# How can i read inside loop in java without runtime error?

Tags: java, string, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new in java and try to solve some problem(for practice) with it but I am getting runtime error and can't to know why or what I should search to know why that does.

This is my code.

Runtime error occur when I paste the test into the console but when I write it the runtime doesn't occur

And this is the link of the problem if that can help you to understand my error

https://codeforces.com/contest/1374/problem/C

```
    import java.util.*;
 
 
public class Main {
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = reader.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> anss = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int tst = 0; tst < t; tst++){
            int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            String s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            int ans = 0;
            int open = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(s.charAt(i) == ')'){
                    if(open == 0) ans++;
                    else open--;
                } else {
                    open++;
                }
            }
            anss.add(ans);
        }
        for(int i : anss) System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the exception happening? Do you have a stack trace of it?

Comment: There is no need to construct a new instance of Scanner each time you want to read from the console.  Just create it once at the beginning, and then use the same instance each time you want to get input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read that text, as provided by the Codeforces problem, you'll need to do two things:

- Re-use the existing `Scanner` you've created (instead of creating a new one for each subsequent read)
- Use [`Scanner.next`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) instead of [`Scanner.nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

To the first point, when a `Scanner` starts to parse the `InputStream` (when calling `nextInt` for example), it will consume a fair chunk of the stream. In this case, it consumes the entire stream, and so creating another `Scanner` operating on the same `InputStream` will fail when the stream is read.

To the second, although the documentation for `nextLine` seems to indicate that the whole line will be returned:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

it actually seems to ignore the first token, ie the first non-whitespace part of the line. In this case, each line has no whitespace, so `next` will return the string you need. In the general case, it looks like getting the entire line revolves around doing something like:

```
String s = reader.next() + reader.nextLine();
```

Comment: I got it, thank you very much.
But why each line has no whitespace in the test ?
I mean what are those line separators in the test or what does java understand them when I copy and paste the test in the console ?

Comment: @ahmadalghadban, from my tests locally, you can paste the contents of the input (in particular the example from Codeforces) and it operates as expected. Depending on your OS you can pipe the contents to the execution as well, which operates the same way, submitting the text via standard input to the executable. Under macOS/Linux it's `cat test.txt | java Main`

Comment: ... and under Windows it's `type test.txt | java Main`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to ask user for line length because you can calculate it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = reader.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> anss = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int tst = 0; tst < t; tst++){
        String s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        int ans = 0;
        int open = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == ')'){
                if(open == 0) ans++;
                else open--;
            } else {
                open++;
            }
        }
        anss.add(ans);
    }
    for(int i : anss) System.out.println(i);
}
```